# Push notification with Compact Framework using ServiceStack

Tags: push-notification, compact-framework, servicestack

I want to implement push notifications to my client application working on windows mobile with compact framework 3.5.
For accessing remote data it uses servicestack/protobuf on the server (self hosted in my server application) and standard httpwebrequests (servicestack is not supported on CF)  with protobuf on the clients.

My idea is to use httprequests with long timeouts, where connection is kept open and the notification sent as answer when available.

Considering less than 300 operating clients, my question, before starting to code this (and eventually fail miserably) is: is it acceptable for a servicestack selfhosted server to keep 300 connections continuously open? plus the "normal" opening/closing calls.

Thanks!